# How to get class id of a button in jquery?

Tags: jquery

How to get class id of a button in jquery?
I am trying with this code.

```
<div><button id="Button2" class="Default">2. Click to get Class ID.</button> </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see a better answer below man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="button" id="btn1" class="btnclass" onclick="alert(this.className);" />
```

**or**

```
document.getElementById('btn1').onclick = function () { alert(this.className); }
```

The second option is the better way to do things.

Comment: this returns a list of classes

Answer (score 6):

```
$("#myButton").click( function() {
     var class = $(this).attr("class");
});
```

Note that this can potentially contain multiple classes though.

If you need to check if a specific class exists in the CSS class list:

```
$("#myButton").click( function() {
     var isHighlighted = $(this).hasClass("highlight");
});
```

There's also addClass() and removeClass(). Generally there should be very little reason to ever retrieve the full class attribute as a string - it's much easier to manipulate or compare the attribute by using the jQuery methods instead.

Comment: This one is good a answer. Is there way to get that as a value and not true false. Hence, as you said I am looking for a specific class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind [**`click`**](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event to button first and then use jQuery **[`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** to get the class.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/ghcsb/)**

```
$('#Button2').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('class'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the ids of the clicked button then just capture the target's id of the clicked event:

see this in the fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/DhjBW/**

this the html:

```
<span></span>

<button id='button 1'>btn1</button>
<button id='button 2'>btn2</button>
<button id='button 3'>btn3</button>
```

this the jQuery:

```
$("button").click(function(e) {
    $('span').text($(e.target).attr("id"));
});
```